# How to get a duplicate instance on save in Django?

Tags: python, django

Supposing I already have a created instance of a Django's model. I want to get another instance that is a duplicate in the database. Is there a universal way to do it without finding out which unique index is responsible for this duplication:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

instance = MyModel(...)
print(instance.id)  # None

...

duplicate = get_duplicate(instance)  # what should I type here instead of get_duplicate?
print(duplicate.id)  # Some ID in DB
```

I want the function `get_duplicate` to not depend on the internal structure of the model. Also I don't want to modify the model.

For example, if I need to find out a duplicate exists I can do `instance.save()`. In case of `IntegrityError` there's a duplicate. But how to find out which one?

Comment: Perhaps you would find `get_or_create` useful. Django doesn't have a `get_duplicate` method. You could probably build one by introspecting the models, but there will be subtleties like fields that allow `null`, so it might not be simple.

Comment: Yes, `get_or_create` could help. But the instance is already created, so I can't use it.

Comment: Then you could restructure your code to use `get_or_create`, write a specific `get_duplicate` method for your model (easy), or write a generic `get_duplicate` model (harder) by introspecting `MyModel._meta`.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a model as such `MyModel(...)`, you get an unsaved instance.  To propagate it to the database, you have to call `.save()` on it, at which point `instance.id` will be set to something.  You could also do `MyModel.objects.create(...)` as a shortcut.

Now, to answer the question, to duplicate a record you already have in the database; set its `id` to `None`, and save it again.

```
instance = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
instance.id = None
instance.save()
print(instance.id)  # 2
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want `.save()` to create two database rows instead of one?  I don't understand why you'd want that, or how you'd make it useful, but you'd do it by overriding `.save()` on your model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        instance.id = None
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

---

As for *finding* a duplicate instance, this is much more difficult.  You're going to have to decide what makes an instance a "duplicate".  If it's a user model, for instance, maybe if only the email address is the same, it's a duplicate, but if it's a transaction instance, then EVERY field has to be the same.

As this is to inextricably linked to the model's type, you will want to put this on the model itself.  I'll write a toy example below:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)
    b = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)
    c = models.CharField(...)

    def get_duplicates(self):
        return type(self).filter(
            a=self.a,
            b=self.b,
        )
```

In this example, `a` and `b` must match, but `c` doesn't have to.

You've already defined what makes a model a "duplicate" with your unique and unique together keys, so your `.get_duplicates()` function should be informed by those.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve my problem. I don't want to modify the code of the model. I just need a way to find a duplicate if it exists by given instance. For example, I created this instance first, had done some calculations with it and after that I want to check for a duplicate in DB. Can I do it easily without modifying the model?

Comment: Right, your question wasn't clear.  You're looking to _find_ a duplicate instance, not _create_ one.  I'll update my answer, but be warned - there's no easy way.

Comment: Could you post your model please.

Comment: Updated my answer.